# rewriting quantifiers using propostional expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let the domain of the propositional function P(x) be D={a,b,c}. Express the following quantified statements without using quantifiers but as logical expressions of P(a), P(b) and P(c) using AND, OR, or NOT operators.

a) $∀x \in D,P(x)$

b) $∃x \in D,P(x)$

c)(NOT)[$∃x \in D,P(x)]$

I don't understand what I'm supposed to do exactly with this question. I understand that I'm supposed to use the propositional logic symbols to rewrite the statement. But have no clue how to go about doing it.

Comment: Is E supposed to be $\in$?

Comment: Because the *domain* is *finite* you can "expand" an universally quantified formula as a (finite) *conjunction* and an existentially quantified formula as a (finite) *disjunction*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all just gets and'd together and there exists just gets or'd together:

1. $\forall x \in D, P(x) = P(a) \wedge P(b) \wedge P(c)$

   $\exists x \in D, P(x) = P(a) \vee P(b) \vee P(c)$

   $\neg \left(\exists x \in D, P(x)\right) = \neg\left(P(a) \vee P(b) \vee P(c)\right) = \neg P(a) \wedge \neg P(b) \wedge \neg P(c)$