# Write expressions w/out quantifiers (convert to AND/OR expressions)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

> 2. A universe contains the three individuals $a,b$, and $c$. For these individuals, a predicate $Q(x,y)$ is defined, and its truth values are given by the following table:
>      \begin{array}{c|ccc}
>    x\backslash y&a&b&c\\\hline
>    a&T&F&T\\
>    b&F&T&F\\
>    c&F&T&T
>    \end{array}
>      Write each of the following expressions without quantifiers (i.e. covert them to expressions with ANDs and ORs or both) and then evaluate the expression.
>      a) $\forall x\,\exists y\,Q(x,y)$
>      b) $\forall y\,Q(y,b)$
>      c) $\forall y\,Q(y,y)$

I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728196/rewriting-quantifiers-using-propostional-expressions) which says to convert all $\exists$ to OR and all $\forall$ to AND. However, my problem has 2 variables (instead of one, like in the aforementioned example). I'm not sure how to handle that.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW9Ve.png)

---

**My attempts**:

a) $[P(a,a)\lor P(b,a)\lor P(c,a)]\land [P(b,a)\lor P(b,b)\lor P(b,c)]\land [P(c,a)\lor P(c,b)\lor P(c,c)]$

b) $P(a,b)\land P(b,b)\land P(c,b)$

c) $P(a,b)\land P(a,c)\land P(b,a)\land P(b,c)\land P(c,a)\land P(c,b)$

<s>I am unsure how to evaluate the expressions..</s>

To evaluate the expressions, I just need to match the "coordinates" with their respective T/F then evaluate whether or not the whole expression is T/F from there. Correct?

Comment: I think you're thinking about the right method, but for a), there's a mistake in the first pair of brackets, and in c), you should have only three terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, my problem has 2 variables (instead of one, like in the aforementioned example). I'm not sure how to handle that.
>
> a) $[P(a,a)\lor P(b,a)\lor P(c,a)]\land [P(b,a)\lor P(b,b)\lor P(b,c)]\land [P(c,a)\lor P(c,b)\lor P(c,c)]$

**Almost** as you did; but not quite (you muddled up the first grouping).  (Also, mind your Pees and Queues.)

When in doubt, write it out, just one step at a time. $$\begin{align}
&\qquad \forall x~\exists y~Q(x,y) 
\\ & \equiv \big(\exists y~Q(a, y)\big)\wedge\big(\exists y~Q(b, y)\big)\wedge \big(\exists y~Q(c, y)\big)
\\ & \equiv \big(\exists y~Q(a, y)\big)\wedge\big(\exists y~Q(b, y)\big)\wedge\big(Q(c,a)\vee Q(c,b)\vee Q(c,c)\big)
\\[1ex] & \equiv \big(Q(a,a)\vee Q(a,b)\vee Q(a,c)\big)\wedge\big(Q(b,a)\vee Q(b,b)\vee Q(b,c)\big)\wedge\big(Q(c,a)\vee Q(c,b)\vee Q(c,c)\big)
\\[1ex] & \equiv \big(\mathrm T\vee \mathrm F\vee \mathrm T\big)\wedge\big(\mathrm F\vee \mathrm T\vee \mathrm F\big)\wedge\big(\mathrm F\vee \mathrm T\vee \mathrm T\big)
\\ & \equiv (\mathrm T)\wedge(\mathrm T)\wedge(\mathrm T)
\\ & \equiv \mathrm T
\end{align}$$

> b) $P(a,b)\land P(b,b)\land P(c,b)$

$\forall y\;Q(y,b) = Q(a,b)\land Q(b,b)\land Q(c,b) \quad\checkmark$

> c) $P(a,b)\land P(a,c)\land P(b,a)\land P(b,c)\land P(c,a)\land P(c,b)$

$\forall y\;Q(y,y) = Q(a,a)\land Q(b,b)\land Q(c,c) \quad$ all $y$ within each term are replaced with the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\forall y ~ Q(y, y)$$
>   $$P(a,b)\land P(a,c)\land P(b,a)\land P(b,c)\land P(c,a)\land P(c,b)$$

$$\forall y ~ Q(y, y)$$

Should be

$$Q(a, a) \land Q(b, b) \land Q(c,c)$$

Otherwise you are correct.  Edit: As tunococ pointed out, in *(a)*, $[P(a,a)\lor P(b,a)\lor P(c,a)]$ has a mistake not present in the other two terms.

> To evaluate the expressions, I just need to match the "coordinates" with their respective T/F then evaluate whether or not the whole expression is T/F from there. Correct?

Yes.